# rsyncing - ignoring checksums

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync, checksum, ignore

Trying to copy a bunch of data over and time, unfortunately, is of the essence.  I'd like to do an `rsync` of all the data in one direction, pretty much `rsync` just clobbers what's over on the destination server.  Is there a way to do an `rsync` and just say, "overwrite all files"

Is there a better way of doing this?  We're talking 500GB of data that only has to go in one direction.

Answer (score 5):

Checksums are not used by rsync by default - they have to be enabled with the `-c` flag. From the [manpage](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html):

> -c, --checksum
>
> This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed
>     and  are in need of a transfer.  Without this option, rsync
>   uses a “quick check” that (by default) checks if each file's size
>   and time of last modification match between the sender and receiver.

I don't think the quick, non-checksum calculation will be your limiting factor.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind: use `scp`. For simple copy operations the syntax is the same.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that came to my mind: erase whatever is in the destination folder before `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `-W` option with *rsync* for this purpose.  I haven't fully tested so this may not do what I think it does.  You might also use the `-I` option to enforce clobbering.  From the [manpage](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html):

```
 -W, --whole-file       copy files whole (w/o delta-xfer algorithm)
 -I, --ignore-times     don't skip files that match size and time
```

Comment: Using either of those options will likely increase the transfer time, and using those options together makes it much worse; `-I` by itself will calculate checksums for previously transferred files, `-W` by itself will re-transfer identical portions of files, and `-IW` will re-transfer every file every time.